# pre-commit --comment-style regex

Tags: pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I have a precommit file which checks for commented line format in .cfg files.  The current comment style is a semicolon, so this will fail if a pound sign is used for file comments.  Can RegEx somehow be used to match multiple comment patterns?  For example:

```
      - --comment-style
      - ';'|'#'|'some other comment'
    files: |
      (?x)(
        \.cfg
      )$
```

This is the source of the precommit test:

https://github.com/Lucas-C/pre-commit-hooks/blob/master/tests/insert_license_test.py

Thanks.

Comment: this isn't an issue with pre-commit -- it's whatever tool takes `--comment-style` (which you haven't shown so this isn't answerable)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I'll update it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it cannot

https://github.com/Lucas-C/pre-commit-hooks/blob/556aa509296132b8e2477f0a3e33c9916232e748/pre_commit_hooks/insert_license.py#L32-L35

```
    parser.add_argument('--comment-style', default='#',
                        help='Can be a single prefix or a triplet: '
                             '<comment-start>|<comment-prefix>|<comment-end>'
                             'E.g.: /*| *| */')
```

there is only one comment type that is allowed by that hook